# Generic keyof and property getter function

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I'm trying to observe properties of objects in arrays. To make it type safe I'm using a getter function to get to the child object of the array objects (if necessary) that contain the actual property to be observed.

The `propertyName / key` must a string as the observe library I'm using needs it.

The getter should be able to accept a function that returns the same type as was passed in, like `o => o`.

You can find a condensed example below:

```
function foo<A, B>(
    array: A[], 
    getter: (ao: A) => B, 
    key: keyof B, 
    callback: (value: B[keyof B]) => void
) {
    callback(getter(array[0])[key]);
}

foo([{b: {c: 1}}], a => a.b, "c", v => {});
```

Alas this throws `Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

But the following does work:

```
function bar<A>(
    array: A[], 
    key: keyof A, 
    callback: (value: A[keyof A]) => void
) {
    callback(array[0][key]);
}

bar([{b: 1}], "b", v => {});
```

Why is the compiler not able to infer the type of `B` and is there a workaround I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @jcalz I don't necessarily have a reason, just a workaround. If you do it in a two call approach, you can fix `A` and `B` in a first call, and send the `key` and the `callback` in the second call and then the types will be inferred correctly.

```
function foo2<A, B>(
    array: A[],
    getter: (ao: A) => B,
) {
    return function <K extends keyof B>(key: K, callback: (value: B[K]) => void) {
        callback(getter(array[0])[key]);
    }
}

foo2([{ b: { c: 1, d: "" } }], a => a.b)("d", v => { }); // v is string
foo2([{ b: { c: 1, d: "" } }], a => a.b)("c", v => { }); // v is number
```

It's a bit uglier as far as syntax goes but you get full type safety.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a definitive answer as to why the compiler doesn't infer `B`.  My intuition is that it's much easier for the compiler to infer the type of a parameter you actually pass to the function, than it is for it to infer a type only *related* to the parameter you pass in.  Based on that intuition, I'd rewrite the types to replace `B` with `Record<K,V>`, where `K` is the key you are actually passing in, and `V` is the type of value of the property associated with that key.

In case you're not aware, `Record<K,V>` is part of the TypeScript standard library and is defined like this:

```
type Record<K extends string, T> = {
    [P in K]: T; 
}
```

Then the function becomes:

```
function foo<A, K extends string, V>(
    array: A[], 
    getter: (ao: A) => Record<K,V>, 
    key: K, // easier to infer K because you directly pass it in
    callback: (value: V) => void
) {
    callback(getter(array[0])[key]);
}
```

And this seems to work:

```
foo([{ b: { c: 1 } }], a => a.b, "c", v => { });
```

The parameters are inferred as `<{ b: { c: number; }; }, "c", number>` as desired.

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

#### Update

@TitianCernicovaDragomir points out that the following call:

```
foo([{ b: { c: 1, d: "" } }], a => a.b, "c", v => { });
```

gets inferred as

```
foo<{ b: { c: number; d: string; }; }, "c" | "d", string | number>(...)
```

The problem here is that you want `K` to be just `"c"`, and not `"c" | "d"`, but apparently the `array` parameter was inspected before the `key` parameter.  (I don't think the fact that `V` is `string | number` is the actual problem, since `callback` in fact takes any value whatsoever.  If you passed a `callback` function that only took `number` and it failed, then that would be a problem.)

If you find that some type parameters are inferred in the wrong order (meaning the compiler uses a parameter to infer something, but you would rather it used a different parameter) you can [lower the priority](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) of an inference by intersecting the type with `{}`.

In this case, we can do this:

```
function foo<A, K extends string, V>(
  array: A[],
  getter: (ao: A) => Record<K & {}, V>, // delay inference of K
  key: K, 
  callback: (value: V) => void
) {
  callback(getter(array[0])[key]);
}
```

Now when we call

```
foo([{ b: { c: 1, d: "" } }], a => a.b, "c", v => { });
```

it is inferred as

```
foo<{ b: { c: number; d: string; }; }, "c", {}>(...)
```

which works fine, since the callback doesn't do anything.  If we call

```
foo([{ b: { c: 1, d: "" } }], a => a.b, "c", (v: number): void => { });
```

then it is inferred as

```
foo<{ b: { c: number; d: string; }; }, "c", number>(...)
```

which is fine, right?

Any other use cases we need to support?

Comment: While this workaround compiles if the array element has properties of different types, the inferred type for v will not be tied to the property name. Ex: for `foo5([{ b: { c: 1, d: "" } }], a => a.b, "c", v => { });` `v` will be `number|string` when it should be `number`

Comment: Indeed it seems in the case of a more complex `Record<K, V>` with multiple property types the return type becomes `any`

Comment: If there are use cases you care about supporting it would be helpful to have them in the text of the question.

Comment: The `any` type probably resulted from a compiler errorr related to using a getter like `o => o`. This is a use case I have, but could create a simplified version of the function for that case. But still, @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's point stands.

Comment: I've updated the signature to support that use case.  If you have more things you need to support, please update the text of your question so that others who want to answer can see the full scope of the problem in the question instead of reading through comments.  Thanks!

Comment: In your second approach you now have to supply the type of the callback manually, which seems to suggest that it is not type safe?